# Integrating Google+ Login Authentication for Web Applications

Tags: google-plus

I need to integrate Google+ to my web applications to allow users to login with their google credentials.  I care nothing about the other API's (retrieving data for use with other google apps) but of course, I'll need the token which should be standard.

Additionally, I have hundreds of of web apps to implement this for.  Do I really need to create a separate project in Google API console for each site?  I thought I could just setup OAuth 2.0 somehow and get things going.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I really need to create a separate project in Google API console for each site?

No you don't need to do that and in fact you're only allowed a limited number of projects. Rather, you're probably better off creating OAuth client IDs for each of your sites and specifying its particular origins and authorized redirect URIs.